# BatchUpsert with Golang and Gorm deadlock in concurrency goroutines

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm, database-deadlocks

I want to get data from one table periodically and analyze it, then dump it to another table.

In the way I did `not use parallelism`, it was `slower and without problems`. Therefore, I want to change to `parallel processing`, but there is a deadlock problem.

As follows, I get the `other_table` data, and then the `json string in column8` is processed and saved to another table `example_table` in `column2,column3,column4,column5`

Examples are as follows

1. *database*

Column1 of both tables are the same

```sql
CREATE TABLE `other_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
  `column1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `column7` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `column8` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `udx_column1` (`column1`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='other_table';

CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
  `column1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `column2` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `column3` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `column4` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `column5` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '' ,
  `deleted_at` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '删除时间',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `udx_column1_column2_column3_deleted_at` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`deleted_at`),
  KEY `idx_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='example_table';
```

2. gorm code

```golang
// Update if exist, create if not .
func (e *example) BatchUpsert(ctx context.Context, es []*model.Example) error {
    return e.db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
        Columns: []clause.Column{
            {Name: "column1"},
            {Name: "column2"},
            {Name: "column3"},
        },
        UpdateAll: true,
    }).Create(&es).Error
}
```

3.Concurrent code
Improves efficiency by splitting data for parallel processing, but causes **database deadlocks**
Parse the data in column8 of `other_table` into column2,column3,column4,column5 of `example_table`

> ps: The whole code is wrapped in a cron package("github.com/robfig/cron/v3")

```golang
const (
    DataSize    = 100
    DataPerTask = 10
)
type Task struct {
    index int
    datas  []model.OtherData
    sum   int
    wg    *sync.WaitGroup
}

func handler(string) []model.Example(){}

func (t *Task) Do() {
    for _, d := range t.datas {
        // after some hander,  get example_table slice data
        examples := handler(d.column8)
        
        if err := example.BatchUpsert(ctx, examples);err!=nil{
            log.Errorf(err)
        }
        
    }
    t.wg.Done()
}
taskFunc := func(data interface{}) {
    task := data.(*Task)
    task.Do()
}

// length=100, from other get 
nums:=[100]*model.OtherData

p, _ := ants.NewPoolWithFunc(10, taskFunc)
defer p.Release()
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(DataSize / DataPerTask)
tasks := make([]*Task, 0, DataSize/DataPerTask)
for i := 0; i < DataSize/DataPerTask; i++ {
    task := &Task{
        index: i + 1,
        nums:  nums[i*DataPerTask : (i+1)*DataPerTask],
        wg:    &wg,
    }
    tasks = append(tasks, task)
    p.Invoke(task)
}
wg.Wait()
```

### Personal understanding

It stands to reason that the `other_data` I get has a unique index on column1, and that column1 is also used as part of the unique index in the `example_table`. There should be no association between the `upsert data`, but there is a **database deadlock problem**

- `error`

```bash
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
[11.305ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `example_table` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`deleted_at`,`column4`,`column5`) VALUES (),(),(),(),()... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column1`=VALUES(`column1`),`column2`=VALUES(`column2`),`column3`=VALUES(`column3`),`deleted_at`=VALUES(`deleted_at`),`column4`=VALUES(`column4`),`column5`=VALUES(`column5`)
...
Similar deadlock errors
...
```

### Expected answer

Is it because I'm using upsert, or is it the wrong version, or something else? Looking forward to the reply

> - go version: 1.16
> - gorm.io/driver/mysql v1.3.2
> - gorm.io/gorm v1.23.2
> - gorm.io/plugin/soft_delete v1.2.0

### mysql status

```bash
mysql> show engine innodb status;
...
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-03-01 14:20:33 0x7f2be4264700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 188178, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 46334, OS thread handle 139826491008768, query id 1037015 10.86.40.52 root update
INSERT INTO `example_table` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`deleted_at`,`column4`,`column5`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?,
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 191 page no 17 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `examle_db`.`example_table` trx id 188178 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 188179, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
8 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 46338, OS thread handle 139826488035072, query id 1037016 10.86.40.52 root update
INSERT INTO `example_table` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`deleted_at`,`column4`,`column5`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?,
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 191 page no 17 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `examle_db`.`example_table` trx id 188179 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 191 page no 17 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `examle_db`.`example_table` trx id 188179 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
...
```